# Using sed to cut up a log file

Tags: sed, grep

I am tailing a log file and using grep to cut out just the lines that I want info for, now I want to pipe that into sed to trim the fat per se.

For example the original log is:

```
Feb  9 17:48:21 dnsmasq[884]: query[A] captive.g.aaplimg.com from 192.168.178.21
Feb  9 17:48:21 dnsmasq[884]: forwarded captive.g.aaplimg.com to 8.8.4.4
Feb  9 17:48:21 dnsmasq[884]: reply captive.g.aaplimg.com is 17.253.55.202
Feb  9 17:48:21 dnsmasq[884]: reply captive.g.aaplimg.com is 17.253.55.204
```

Then i use grep --line-buffered "query" to get just the query lines:

```
Feb  9 18:42:21 dnsmasq[884]: query[A] captive.g.aaplimg.com from 192.168.178.21
Feb  9 18:42:40 dnsmasq[884]: query[A] sb.scorecardresearch.com from 192.168.178.21
Feb  9 18:42:51 dnsmasq[884]: query[A] captive.g.aaplimg.com from 192.168.178.21
Feb  9 18:43:06 dnsmasq[884]: query[A] captive-cidr.origin-apple.com.akadns.net from 192.168.178.21
Feb  9 18:43:06 dnsmasq[884]: query[AAAA] captive-cidr.origin-apple.com.akadns.net from 192.168.178.21
Feb  9 18:43:21 dnsmasq[884]: query[A] time-macos.apple.com from 192.168.178.21
```

Now I have as a command:

```
sudo tail -F /var/log/pihole.log  | grep --line-buffered "query" | sed -E 's/(\query).*(\from)/\1 \2/'
```

Because I want to cut out elements so it goes to:

```
18:42 captive.g.aaplimg.com
18:42 sb.scorecardresearch.com
18:42 captive.g.aaplimg.com
18:43 captive-cidr.origin.apple.com
```

and so forth.

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You are making no attempt to capture the time from the third field (e.g. `18:42`). Writing a sed command that will do what you want is simple, but tedious. Can you write one that will remove the leading date (`Feb. 9 `)?

Comment: I'm really new to sed, unix and coding in general and honestly I'm really not sure, I made this account out of desparation to see what to learn hahaha could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Even if I try to cut out the time with: sed -r 's/[0-9]{1,2}\:[0-9]{1,2}\1\2/' i end up with nothing

Comment: I don't know what flavor of sed you're using, but that doesn't appear to be a well-formed substitution command. Try `sed 's/.......//' filename` and see what happens. Do you understand how it works?

Comment: @KallumR, can you explain why the output consists of only **those** 4 lines? Why doesn't it contain `18:43 time-macos.apple.com` too?

Answer (score 0):

The following command extracts the info you want (hours, minutes, and what's between `query` and `from`, as you describe with your last 4 lines chunck of code) from the 6 lines you describe as the output of `grep`.

```
sed -E 's/.*([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}):.*query\[[^]]*\] (.*) from .*/\1 \2/'
```